# How to make a new powerup reset the WaitForSeconds from previous powerup?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm making a game where the player is pushing objects outside a plane. Every round there's an additional ball (GameManager.cs):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < enemiesToSpawn; i++)
```

But every round the player gets a powerup as well:

```
 if (enemyCount == 0)
    {
       roundNumber++;
       SpawnEnemyIntruders(roundNumber);
       Instantiate(powerup, GenerateSpawnPosition(), powerup.transform.rotation);
    }
```

In the PlayerController.cs the code looks like this:

```
   private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Powerup"))
    {
        hasPowerup = true;
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        StartCoroutine(PowerupCountdown());
        powerupParticle.Play();
        playerAudio.PlayOneShot(powerupSound, 1.0f);
    }
}

IEnumerator PowerupCountdown()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    hasPowerup = false;
    powerupParticle.Stop();
}
```

How can I reset the WaitForSeconds, or do something similar, every time the player gets a powerup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a timer as class' member instead of a local variable in your coroutine.

```
private float powerupTimer;
private IEnumerator powerupCoroutine;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Powerup"))
    {
        hasPowerup = true;
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        powerupTimer += 5;
        if(powerupCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(powerupCoroutine);
        powerupCoroutine = PowerupCountdown();
        StartCoroutine(powerupCoroutine);
        powerupParticle.Play();
        playerAudio.PlayOneShot(powerupSound, 1.0f);
    }
}

IEnumerator PowerupCountdown()
{
    for(; powerupTimer > 0 ; powerupTimer -= Time.deltaTime)
       yield return null;
    hasPowerup = false;
    powerupParticle.Stop();
}
```

---

However, I believe you should rework your power up system. The player class should not be responsible for all this logic (handling timer, particles, ...)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to clean up my code. I'll try to move as much as possible into the GameManager and/or make a cs-file just for the powerup. It's my first game ever, so I'm learning a lot along the way.

Comment: And just so I'm entirely sure how to understand every bit of the code: What does the first semicolon mean? `for(; powerupTimer > 0 ; powerupTimer -= Time.deltaTime)`

Comment: I know it's the initializer, but why can it be empty in this case?

Comment: It's empty because we don't want to give an initial value to powerupTimer. The value is "reset" in the `OnTriggerEnter` function.